# Perl read subsection inside open file handle

Tags: perl, filehandle

I have open a file using:

```
open (FH, "<".$File::Find::name) or die "cannot open file \"".$File::Find::name." \"!";
while (<FH>) {
  ...my code...  
}
```

I parse the lines using Regular expressions to get the data I want.
Now I want to read a subsection of a file until I see the ending of that subsection inside my while-loop.
i.e: reading from "StartSection" until "EndSection" line by line:

```
open (FH, "<".$File::Find::name) or die "cannot open file 
\"".$File::Find::name." \"!";
while (<FH>) {
  ...my code...
  if (/^StartSection$/) {
    while (<FH> !~ /^EndSection) {
      ... more code....
    }
  }
}
```

How must I program this correctly in Perl?

Comment: The words are "Perl" and "file handle", not "PERL" and "FileHandler".

Comment: Better use `open my $fh, '<', $filename   ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of several ways to answer this question, but I'll go with the [flip-flop operator](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Range-Operators) answer:

```
while (<FH>) {
   if (/^StartSection$/ .. /^EndSection/) {
       ... special code ...
   } else {
       ... regular code ...
   }
}
```

Comment: How will the code read the next line(S) of <FH> inside the if section?